# How to point subdomain to a Heroku app, and root domain to another Heroku app?

Tags: heroku, dns

I'm having trouble with routing a subdomain to a Wordpress blog hosted on Heroku, and the root domain to another Heroku app.

If I have purchased a domain called `cheese.com` on NameCheap and I'd like to route a subdomain like `blog.cheese.com` how could I do this on Heroku?

What type of setting would I need to place on each Heroku application?

Comment: I believe that wilcards is the best option like say [@Ved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715556/how-to-point-subdomain-to-a-heroku-app-and-root-domain-to-another-heroku-app/13748449#13748449)

Answer (score 98, accepted):

I'm not sure of exact directions for NameCheap but the general way to redirect a subdomain to the Heroku app would be to add a CNAME record to the subdomain. To redirect the root domain you will need to set a CNAME like functionality at the zone apex.

**Subdomain**

blog.cheese.com would have a CNAME record pointing to myblog.herokuapp.com, you may also want to create a CNAME record for www.blog.cheese.com.

An example record could be:

```
Name: blog.cheese.com
TTL: 14400
Type: CNAME
Address: myblog.herokuapp.com
```

Once both CNAME records are set up you will need to tell heroku to point the domain to your app.

```
heroku domains:add --app myblog blog.cheese.com
```

If you do this for both your subdomains they should now point to your Heroku apps.

**Root Domain**

To point the root domain you will need to set a couple of records

```
Host Name: @      
URL: http://www.cheese.com                
Record Type: URL Redirect

Host Name: www            
URL: mymainpage.herokuapp.com              
Record Type: CNAME (alias)
```

Once both records are setup just call the command below via Heroku to point your domains to it.

```
heroku domains:add --app mymainpage.herokuapp.com cheese.com
```

Here are a couple of places to look for extra information.

[Point namecheap domain to Heroku](http://blog.romansanchez.me/2013/06/08/point-namecheap-domain-to-heroku/)

[Custom Domains | Heroku Dev Center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains)

Comment: How do I create a cname for subdomain?

Comment: @Saurabh You'll need to take a look at your domain records either through your domain host, your hosting provider or through a service like Route 53 by AWS. Whichever place your nameservers are pointing to :)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add the custom domain to your heroku app - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains - 
After setting the necessary DNS, you can add the wildcards