# How to use a non-www domain with heroku?

Tags: http, heroku, web, http-status-code-301

I know they don't support it, but seriously, how to do it? Point A-records to an ip which only serves up a 301 to heroku? That sounds really dumb. Am I missing something?

Is there a simpler workaround?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a simpler workaround.

Point your www CNAME to myapp.herokuapp.com

Then forward your root url (myapp.com) to www.myapp.com

Comment: can you detail what you mean with "forward your root url"? is this in a dns zone, or within heruku or app ?

Comment: I agree this answer could include more detail.

Answer (score 12):

According to [Heroku's documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#apex-domains-examplecom):

> Zone apex domains (aka “naked” domains or “bare” domains), for example `example.com`, are not officially supported on Heroku apps, because DNS forbids CNAME records on the zone apex. However, some DNS hosts provide a way to get CNAME-like functionality at the zone apex.
>
> For each provider, the setup is similar: point the ALIAS or ANAME entry for your apex domain to myapp.herokuapp.com, just as you would with a CNAME record.

Heroku's documentation mentioned these providers with "CNAME" support for zone apex:

- [ANAME at DNS Made Easy](http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com/technology/aname-records/)
- [ALIAS at DNSimple](http://support.dnsimple.com/questions/32826-What-is-an-ALIAS-record)

Besides, these providers also work:

- [CloudFlare](http://blog.cloudflare.com/zone-apex-naked-domain-root-domain-cname-supp)
- [{A}Record](http://www.arecord.net/)

And most DNS providers (such as [ClouDNS](http://www.cloudns.net/features/) and [Namecheap FreeDNS](http://www.namecheap.com/products/freedns.aspx)) have free webhop / web redirect, so you don't need to setup your own web server for the redirect.

Comment: This helpful piece from DNSimple may be of interest http://support.dnsimple.com/questions/32923-CloudFlare-Current-Best-Practices

Answer (score 2):

For NameCheap: 
@ goes to "http://www.example.com"
www goes to "myHeroku.herokuapp.com."

Also, checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715556/how-to-point-subdomain-to-a-heroku-app-and-root-domain-to-another-heroku-app)

Answer (score 1):

Heroku does not have its own DNS management, hence you will need to host your dns outside and point records to heroku. Here's the solution (I am using route 53 to manage DNS- it's free)

1.Add domain to heroku- www.example.com , after this heroku will give a CNAME record

2.Add this CNAME record to route 53

3.Create an s3 bucket called example.com and set redirect to www.example.com said by https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/root-domain-website-hosting-for-amazon-s3/

4.(Skip this step if you dont need HTTPS)create cloudfront instance and configure with s3 bucket link of www.example.com and add cname entry only for www.example.com.

5.In route 53,Create an A record for example.com & point alias as cloudfront link related to s3 bucket for example.com point alias s3 bucket of example.com

6.Done